# Get page size using AlivePDF

Tags: dimension, alivepdf

Is it possible to get the page width and page height for a PDF during creation with AlivePDF?

I need this to place a shape to the right side of the page, no margin or padding, sticked to the right side.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this will help you. Looking at the AlivePDF API documentation for the Page object (See [here](http://alivepdf.bytearray.org/alivepdf-asdoc/org/alivepdf/pages/Page.html)) I've found the public properties "width" and "height".

In my code, given a PDF object called myPDF, I use:

```
var sizeWidth:int = myPDF.getPage(i).width;
var sizeHeight:int = myPDF.getPage(i).height;
```

to get the width and height of page **i**.